# Unicode in R strings for graph labels -- begin "down converted"

Tags: r, unicode, ggplot2

I have the following code that makes this excellent graph.

```
ggplot(table3, aes(x=Text, y=Value, color = Type)) + geom_point(size = 3,aes(shape=Dataset)) + geom_line(lwd=0.7,aes(group=Var)) + labs(title="Fungal Classification Accuracy") + labs(x="count method and threshold", y="number genera detected")
```

[image: my graph without unicode]
As you can see, I get the labels written with ">=" characters.

I tried to add this code to make an upgrade:

```
> table3$Text <- rep(c("count > 0","count \u2265 1","unique \u2265 1","unique \u2265 5","unique \u2265 9"),4)
> table3$Text
[1] "count > 0"  "count ≥ 1"  "unique ≥ 1" "unique ≥ 5" "unique ≥ 9" "count > 0"  "count ≥ 1"  "unique ≥ 1"
[9] "unique ≥ 5" "unique ≥ 9" "count > 0"  "count ≥ 1"  "unique ≥ 1" "unique ≥ 5" "unique ≥ 9" "count > 0" 
[17] "count ≥ 1"  "unique ≥ 1" "unique ≥ 5" "unique ≥ 9"
```

[image: my graph with unicode, incorrectly typing characters]

As you can see it "down converts" the ≥ to = sign.  I noticed that also the default printing of the table does the same thing, but I don't know what to do to fix it.

```
        Text Dataset X Type      Var Value
1  count > 0     SDS 0  TPR  SDS.TPR 0.447
2  count = 1     SDS 1  TPR  SDS.TPR 0.447
3 unique = 1     SDS 2  TPR  SDS.TPR 0.447
4 unique = 5     SDS 3  TPR  SDS.TPR 0.447
5 unique = 9     SDS 4  TPR  SDS.TPR 0.426
6  count > 0    SMDS 0  TPR SMDS.TPR 0.447
```

Reading other stack overflow questions, other suggestions are mentioned:

(A) Don't use windows: I am using windows, but if the easiest fix is to jump to another computer, so be it.  (Untested)

(B) Use sprintf() on the unicode string.  This did not help in this case, suggesting to me the down converting may be somehow tied to the data frame.

(C) Turn on UTF-8 encoding.  This did not work, although I am unsure if I did it correctly.

```
table3$Text <- rep(c(sprintf("count > 0"),sprintf("count \u2265 1"),sprintf("unique \u2265 1"),sprintf("unique \u2265 5"),sprintf("unique \u2265 9")),4)
Encoding("UTF-8")
```

EDIT

In comments, extra information requested

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] labeling_0.3     MASS_7.3-40      colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.2.5     magrittr_1.5     plyr_1.8.3      
 [7] tools_3.2.0      gtable_0.1.2     reshape2_1.4.1   Rcpp_0.12.0      stringi_0.5-5    grid_3.2.0      
[13] stringr_1.0.0    digest_0.6.8     proto_0.3-10     munsell_0.4.2
```

Comment: Could you post your `sessionInfo()` or `Sys.getlocale()`? , maybe an encoding issue

Comment: Post updated with the information.

Comment: Well, it worked on Ubuntu 14.04 with R 3.2.1 no problems.

Answer (score -2):

It works on Ubuntu 14.04 with R 3.2.1 (both amd64).

Final answer: Don't use windows.